# CSS exact child selector

Tags: css

I know that greater than (>) sign/slector will select exact child and not nested one

but in this example all `<li>` getting black BG

```
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item With ul
        <ul>
            <li>Sub list item</li>
            <li>Sub list item</li>
            <li>Sub list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content > ul li {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

as per rule black BG shouldn't be for  **Sub list item** but here its applied to all `<li>` (should be just for **List Item With**)

http://jsfiddle.net/4j1zv25b/

Comment: you have this part `ul li` which will select all the li you probably want `#content > ul > li`

Comment: can you please tell us what you are trying to do. thanks

Comment: `>` doesn't select exact child. Selects all the elements that are children of that element ( but not grandchildren or other descendants ) . So `content > ul li ` will select ALL li inside the `ul` which is a direct child of the `#content`. SO in your example, that means all your `li` from your HTML structure will be selected. So the css is working as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code selects any `li` within the first level `ul`. The child list `li` tags are still descendants of the first `ul` so get styled. You need to also use select the direct descendant of the `ul`:

```
#content > ul > li {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

However, you also have the issue that all child lists are inside of that styled `li`. The child elements don't have a background or color set so the background is transparent and the color is inherited. You need to apply a new background and color to override those styles.

```css
#content>ul>li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#content li li {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item With ul
      <ul>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test this? Because this doesn't work. Tested it myself using the jsfiddle provided.

Comment: See my edit. It does work, the child elements just don't have a background or color set so the background is transparent and the color is inherited.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Was about to post it. I would explain some more about main styling and overrides to be complete. But great post now. :)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you've described is correct, because your asking the direct ul child of #content, to style it's Li's with that behaviour.

Just because you've given that Li some children, does not negate its effects. Because the children are within the scope of the original targeted Li, they will be styled according to their parent.

I've attached a potential variant that you may be looking for, which should style just the first li within the sub categories.

I've also attached another example, which might better illustrate my point. Imagine a Div, with another Div inside of it, and inside the child div, there is a paragraph tag.

If you style the direct child of the first div, you would expect the paragraph tag to still have a black background, because it's parent is the targeted div. The p doesn't apply opposite styling to compensate, because why would it?

```css
#content>ul li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#desired>ul li ul li:first-child {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#example > div {
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item With ul
      <ul>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="desired">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item With ul
      <ul>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
        <li>Sub list item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="example">
  <div>
    <p>Still styled</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The greater than symbol (>) selects the direct child of the parent but grandchildren will still inherit from it.

To select the garndchild you would need `ul li ul li` or `ul > li > ul > li`

You can also use child selectors like:

```
:first-child
:nth-child(n)
:last-child
```

See more about CSS selectors here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

why dont you select the inner list items also

```
#content > ul li {background: black;
    color: white;}


#content > ul li li {
    background: white;
    color: black;
 }
```